# How to setup autossh tunnel for MongoDB

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel, mongodb

Here's my setup -

I have two VPS ( linodes ). Linode1 has MongoDB on it. I need to access this MongoDB from Linode2. But, I don't want other users on the private network sneak my data, so I need to use autossh.

I ran `autossh -M 5122 -N -R 27017:linode1ip:27017 linode1ip` on Linode2 but then I am 
prompted to enter password for `root@linode1ip`.

What I expect is, when I successfully execute (after modification) the above command, I can connect to mongo from Linode2 simply using `mongo 127.0.0.1:27017`. Am I wrong about this assumption?

Thank you,all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second `-M` in your command isn't required and will (if the command line you have posted is correct)  cause you to get a `Bad remote forwarding specification 'linode1ip'`

The command that you want to setup the tunnel is

`autossh -M 20000 -N -p 22 USER@LINODE1IP -L 27017/localhost/27017` (edited)

This will setup an ssh tunnel between localhost:27017 on linode2 and port 27017 on linode1.

If you want to get this setup without having to provide a password you will have to setup public key authentication and ssh-agent.

Comment: That was a typo.

Comment: I setup public key auth and tried the command, no luck.

Comment: Thanks. I updated the answer with the command that worked.

Comment: where did the number `20000` come from (similarly what's the `5122` in the OP's question)?

Comment: also how can this command be done with a private key rather than user/pass?

Comment: @abbood http://linux.die.net/man/1/autossh will explain the -M. My last paragraph explains the rest.

Comment: @lain this is related http://serverfault.com/questions/597765/how-to-connect-to-mongodb-server-via-ssh-tunnel-using-robomongo

Comment: the -M 20000 tells autossh to use port 20000 to monitor the tunnel

Answer (score 1):

What I understand is that you need a way to exclude the password prompt from your setup? If is it what you want, you need to setup [public-key authentication](http://www.walkernews.net/2008/06/04/auto-ssh-login-by-using-public-key-cryptography/). That way you can pretty much fire-and-forget the connection.

Key authentication for root user is kinda of risky, so maybe you want to use your tunnel as the `mongodb` user or other non-privileged user.

I am not sure of that `autossh` line, but I never really used the tool. Maybe you should try to get a tunnel running using `ssh` first and then add the `autossh` part after all problems are sorted out.