# Connect to mongodb through ssh

Tags: ssh, iptables, mongodb, ssh-tunnel

I'm not sure if it's related to [this one](https://serverfault.com/questions/597765/how-to-connect-to-mongodb-server-via-ssh-tunnel), but I have a similar problem.

The problem is unless I have port 27017 opened, [Robomongo](http://robomongo.org) fails to connect even with "ssh tunnel" option.

[image: screenshot]

Port, address and public key are correct, I'm using the same credentials to connect through ssh.

Here's the part of my iptables INPUT chain:

```
pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
  (...)
  2044   191475 ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:6666 state NEW,ESTABLISHED
    54     6356 ACCEPT     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
   163    15426 DROP       all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere
```

OUTPUT and FORWARD chains are empty

Looking at the traffic in wireshark I see that Robomongo doesn't try to connect to 27017, it connects to 6666 (as it should), but still fails.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are using a version of mongodb that is not supported by Robomongo. See this answer about Robomongo not supporting Version 3.0 of mongodb yet.